# Pass variable from Photoshop to Python

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, photoshop-script

I can pass a variable from Photoshop to Python via a batch file:

Photoshop script
**talk_to_python.jsx**

```
// path of the bat file to execute
var batPath = "D:\\some_path\\some_folder\\talk_to_python.bat"; 

// create a string
var myStr = "Wiggle, wiggle, wiggle wiggle, yeah!";

// This is were we set the environment variable
$.setenv("MY_STR", myStr);

// and we now execute the bat file
File(batPath).execute();
```

Interim batch file
**talk_to_python.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
python D:\\some_path\\some_folder\\talk_to_python.py %MY_STR%
REM ECHO %MY_STR%
TIMEOUT /t 8
```

Python
**talk_to_python.py**

```
import sys
args = sys.argv[1:]
if len(args) != 0:
  s = " ".join(args)

  # print the original string
  print (s)
```

The result is

Wiggle, wiggle, wiggle wiggle, yeah!

My question is: Can this be done without the interim batch file and pass a variable directly from Photoshop ECMAscript to Python and still execute the script? (On a Windows machine)

Answer (score 1):

Yes - use `app.system` so you can skip the bat file.

See [here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/run-shell-script-from-javascript/m-p/11128711) for more.